# libgdx Checkbox increasing size

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I can not get my CheckBox image (so the actual box not the text) to increase in size, I have tried enlarging the cell and the image cell and just nothing! any ideas?

```
public void show() {

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    background = assetManager.get("data/backgrounds/mainMenu.png", Texture.class);
    skin = assetManager.get("data/ui/settings.json", Skin.class);


    table.setBounds(0,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    table.setFillParent(true);


    buttons();


    table.add(settingsLabel);
    table.getCell(settingsLabel).spaceBottom(200);
    table.row();
    table.add(musicCheck);
    table.getCell(musicCheck).spaceBottom(100);
    musicCheck.getCells().get(0).size(100,100);
    musicCheck.getImageCell().size(100, 100);
    table.row();
    table.add(returnButton).width(100).height(100);
    table.getCell(returnButton).spaceBottom(100);
    table.row();
    stage.addActor(table);

    table.debug();
    musicPlayer.playMusic();
}

public void buttons()
{
    settingsLabel = new Label("Settings", skin);

    musicCheck = new CheckBox("Music", skin, "music");

    returnButton = new Button(skin, "return");

}
```

Comment: first off, you should know the .add function returns the cell, so you can easily chain commands to make your code more readable. I believe what you need is a .fill() and then set the correct cell size

Comment: That didnt work.. unless I did it wrong, can you explain more?

Comment: a table contains a logic table. which is sized to contain the cells. which are sized to contain the actors. If a cell size gets set to something else, the cell grows but not the containing actor. if you set the cell to fill it's actor should always get the same size as the cell it is in.